# Qt: HBoxLayout - stop MainWindow from resizing to contents

Tags: qt, resize, qmainwindow, qlayout, qsizepolicy

It seems most people are asking how to make their `QMainWindow` resize to its contents - I have the opposite problem, my MainWindow *does* resize and I don't know why.

When I set my `QLabel` to a longer text, my mainwindow suddenly gets bigger, and I can't find out why that happens.

The following example code basically contains:

- A `QMainWindow`

  - A `QWidget` as central widget

    - A `QVBoxLayout` as a child of that

      - A `LabelBar` inside that.

The `LabelBar` is a `QWidget` which in turn contains:

- A `QHBoxLayout`

  - Two `QLabel`s in that.

After a second, a `QTimer` sets the label to a longer text to demonstrate the issue.

PyQt example code:

```python
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QWidget,
                             QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QSizePolicy)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        cwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(cwidget)
        self.resize(100, 100)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(cwidget)
        vbox.addWidget(QWidget())
        self.bar = LabelBar(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.bar)

        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(lambda: self.bar.lbl2.setText("a" * 100))
        timer.start(1000)

class LabelBar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.lbl1 = QLabel(text="eggs")
        hbox.addWidget(self.lbl1)
        self.lbl2 = QLabel(text="spam")
        hbox.addWidget(self.lbl2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Main window grows because it's the goal of using layouts. Layouts make size requirements for their widgets to ensure that all content is displayed correctly. Requirements depend on child widgets. For example, `QLabel` by default grows horizontally and require space to fit its content. There are many ways to prevent window growing, and the resulting behavior varies:

- You can put `QLabel` in a `QScrollArea`. When label's text is too long, scrollbars will appear.
- You can enable word wrap using `self.lbl2.setWordWrap(True)`. As long as you set text with some spaces, `QLabel` will display it in several lines, and window will grow vertically a bit instead of growing horizontally.
- You can ignore `QLabel`'s size hint using `self.lbl2.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Ignored, QSizePolicy.Fixed)`. `QLabel`'s content will not affect its layout or parent widget size. Too large text will be truncated.

Comment: Number 3 was a good hint - I still wanted the label to resize when there is space (when the other label gets smaller for example). I ended up setting the sizePolicy of my LabelBar to ignored, which did what I want.