# PyQt5: How to hide widgets if no more space is available when resizing the window?

Tags: pyqt5

My PyQt application includes a `QHBoxLayout` which contains two `QLabel`s, one with static text and another with dynamic content.
The minimal code is as follows:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QApplication, QWidget, QSizePolicy
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        mainLabel = QLabel()
        mainLabel.setContentsMargins(10, 5, 10, 5)
        mainLabel.setText('Main Label')
        mainLabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        mainLabel.setStyleSheet("font: 13pt; font-weight: bold; color: darkblue")
        mainLabel.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Ignored, QSizePolicy.Fixed)

        label = QLabel()
        label.setContentsMargins(10, 5, 10, 5)
        label.setText("<span style='color: blue'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</span> <span style='color: red'> consectetur adipiscing elit,</span>")
        label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
        label.setStyleSheet("font: 10pt")

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(mainLabel)
        hbox.addWidget(label)

        mainWidget = QWidget()
        mainWidget.setFixedHeight(50)
        mainWidget.setLayout(hbox)
        mainWidget.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Ignored, QSizePolicy.Fixed)

        self.setCentralWidget(mainWidget)
        self.setFixedHeight(50)

        self.show()
        self.resize(500, 50)

App = QApplication([])
window = Window()
App.exec()
```

The problem is that when I want to shrink the window, the static label (left one) is gradually covered by the dynamic label. So, in some cases, only a portion of the left label is available.
Is it possible to hide the left label when there is no more space available in the `QHBoxLayout` for both labels and show it again when there is enough space?

Comment: Why are you using those size policies?

Comment: These size policies are proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739119/qt-hboxlayout-stop-mainwindow-from-resizing-to-contents) and make it possible to shrink window size by overlapping or cutting off `QLabel`s. But I seek a solution involving hiding/showing rather than overlapping.

Comment: That doesn't seem a very effective UX choice, did you consider using a scroll area instead? In any case, the only way to do so is to override the `resizeEvent()` of the window (or the central widget using a subclass) or eventually `setGeometry()` of a QBoxLayout subclass and then hide the widget after computing the geometries of the labels (but using a size policy for the first label with [`setRetainSizeWhenHidden(True)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsizepolicy.html#setRetainSizeWhenHidden)).